# setImageBitmap does not update ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview

Using the code below, I am adding an image to an ImageView inside `onActivityResult`. The thing is the ImageView does not show the image unless I rotate my phone (i.e. change orientation). Any ideas how to get this image loaded immediately?

Here is my code

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
vUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: vUserImage.invalidate()

Comment: `invalidate` before or after didn't do it.

Comment: Is it possible you're not updating the image on the UI thread?

Comment: What are the values of imgPath and bmp when this code runs? You should be logging them

Answer (score 0):

I decided to load the image asynchronously and now it works. I use an AsyncTask. I load the bitmap in the background and then I pass it to the ImageView inside `onPostExecute`.